# Laravel abstract syntax tree

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on an item rating web app. The idea is that you would create a custom equation with an indefinite amount of variables, constants and operations for each list. Then go through every item in the list and assign values to the variables, calculating the result at the end and doing what you will with it.

I really cannot think of any way of achieving this, perhaps somehow using abstract syntax trees but I have no experience with php-ast (not to mention this extension looks like it doesn't even do that)

I have only just started learning Laravel and am not extremely familiar with PHP, I feel as if the solution is very obvious but I just can't find how to do it. I apologise if this question has already been answered but I've not had any success in finding the answer if it is out there.

Answer (score 1):

I can state **authoritatively** that your requirement has *nothing whatever* to do with "abstract-syntax trees."  (And, that a *framework,* such as Laravel, doesn't and can't have one.)  Therefore, don't follow this white rabbit.

What you need to do is to step back, look at whatever data-structure you are being given as input, *grab a piece of paper and a number-two pencil* (seriously!), and start trying to work out an **algorithm** to come up with the answers that you need.

Please don't try to "do this in the dark."  Ask your co-workers.  Ask your manager!  *(That's part of what [s]he's there for.)*

And, if you can manage to come up with a **specific** question, please feel free to "ask us."  But we can't meaningfully address a request like this.  Good luck! You'll get it!!

Comment: Well, I'm a student and just doing this as a personal project